# Разместить блок по вертикали в центре так чтобы сохранилась адаптивность по высоте

Tags: html, css, responsive

Задача следующая - нужно чтобы родительский div блок был равен высоте содержимого (изображению) и располагался по вертикали в центре при этом адаптивность по высоте сохранялась (само изображение).

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}

*
{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cont {
 display: table;
 
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;  
  height:60%;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

.image
{
  position:relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  /* position: absolute; */
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* top: 0; */
}

.footer {
  background-color:red;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/750x350" alt=""></div>
  <div class="footer">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

пробовал свойство `magrin: auto` и `display:table` но они убивают адаптивность.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вот самый лёгкий способ, как по мне

```css
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal"><img src="https://cs7057.vk.me/c543105/v543105553/2cc66/CmojW96Ya0c.jpg" width="100"></div>
```

Comment: Это хороший метод, но я бы добавил ограничение картинке на 100vh и 100wh, иначе картинка большего размера улетит за края и не будет скролиться.

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понимаю, вам нужно что-то вроде этого:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.img-block img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img-block">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/28/a1/52/28a152eac79125d785e69e13173d9084.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Или в [кодпене](http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/KNzzjE).

Comment: прикрепил скрин к посту,    align-items: center и   justify-content: center от центровали это хорошо, но align-items: center убивает ту самую адаптивность. На скрине видно что родительский блок стал меньше но img не уменьшается пропорционально в высоте а выезжает за пределы блока, как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса и автор пытается сделать высоту картинки примерно такой то пожалуйста высота картинки на весь блок. и футер остался

```js
<div class="cont">
  <div class="image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/750x350" alt=""></div>
  <div class="footer">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}

*
{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cont {
 display: table;
 
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;  
  height:60%;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

img {

    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
   
}

.footer {
  background-color:red;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/750x350" alt=""></div>
  <div class="footer">
  
  </div>
</div>
```